# Problem to install kdenlive 0.9.10 : ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dependencies, video-editor, kde4, kdenlive

I am trying to install kdenlive 0.9.10 on ubuntu 14.04 (with gnome desktop).

I followed the instructions from the official website (https://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu). But no success.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdenlive

I have searched around and many others have the same problem, but no solution until now.

The error I am geting is:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    kdenlive : Depends: libnepomuk4 (>= 4:4.5.85) but it is not going to be  installed 
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

However, I have checked and there is no broken packages in my system. Further, if I try to install the libnepomuk4, I also get errors.

The same problem is reported in this forum: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=269&t=122406

Thanks in advance. I apreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I Have solved this problem using aptitude.

> sudo aptitude install kdenlive

Depending on your systems and kde version and configuration, this command gives you possible solutions.

It worked for me.